# String transformer : Polynomial time approximation schemes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computability-theory

A program P takes a string as an input and returns a string of same length as output.

> **Q** Given two strings A and B how fast can a program tell weather string B cannot be obtained by a recursive application of P over the initial string A ?
>
> **Q** Given P , length L of the strings and the initial string A how fast can a program find the number of L symbol strings which can not be obtained through any finite number of iterations through P of the initial string A ?

The above appear to be the type NP hard problems are; *can these be proved as NP hard* ; what I am interested in schemes which solve them efficiently i.e. have polynomial time complexity.

Comment: You don't say that $P$ itself is polynomial time computable, but do you intend that?

Comment: Yes P *is* polynomial time computable.

Comment: See http://heim.ifi.uio.no/msteffen/download/02/iterating-jlap.pdf

Comment: [Crossposted](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19133) on [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theorem.** There is $P$ for which the reachability problem in your first question is NP hard.

Proof. Suppose we have any NP decision problem $A$, where for any string $a$, we have $a\in A$ if and only if there is a string $b$ of the same length such that a fixed polynomial time program $p$ accepts $(a,b)$ (this form is achievable without loss of generality by padding). Consider now the following algorithm $P$. On strings of the form $(a,x)$, where $x$ has the same length a $a$, our algorithm checks if $p$ accepts $(a,x)$, and if so, outputs a default accepting output. Otherwise, our algorithm outputs $(a,x^+)$, where $x^+$ is the lexicographic successor to $x$ in the space of all strings of that length, unless $x$ was already the lexically maximal string of that length, in which case $P$ outputs a default rejecting output. This program is polynomial time computable, since it takes just a little longer than $p$ does. But notice that iterating $P$ has the effect of searching through the exponential-size space of witnesses. In particular, if $\vec 0$ is the lexically least string, then $(a,\vec 0)$ reaches the default accepting output if and only if there is a witness for $a$, if and only if $a\in A$. So we have reduced $A$ to your problem for this $P$, and so if $A$ is NP-complete, your problem is NP hard. QED

Meanwhile, I don't expect that your problem is always in NP itself, since it seems that one can use exponential size iterations, in the way I just did, and I don't see how to have a polynomial size witness to reachability. (Meanwhile, the reachability problem for some other $P$ can of course be trivial.)

A similar idea shows more:

**Theorem.** There are $P$ for which your reachability problem is PSPACE complete.

Proof. First, let's show that it can be PSPACE hard. Given any program $p$, such that $p(a)$ runs in polynomial space, design a program $P$ to computer from input of the form $(a,c)$, where $c$ is a string that will be regarded as encoding the configuration during the computation of $p(a)$, of the right length for the bounded on the space needed by $p(a)$. Our program $P$ will perform one step of the computation of $p(a)$ by moving $c$ to the next configuration $c^+$ that would arise during the computation of $p$, or a default accepting or rejecting string if $p(a)$ should halt right at this step of computation. Thus, iterating $P$ corresponds to undertaking the computation of $p(a)$. Therefore, we can reduce the question about whether $p$ accepts or rejects $a$ to the question of whether a certain string is reachable from $(a,c_0)$, where $c_0$ is the starting configuration for $p(a)$. So every PSPACE decidable question reduces to one of your reachability decision problems, and so by using a PSPACE complete $p$, we see that one of your decision problems is PSPACE hard.

Finally, we show that all your reachability problems are themselves in PSPACE. To see if $B$ is reachable from $A$ via $P$, we simply compute successive iterates $P^k(A)$, while at the same time incrementing a counter to count up to the total number of strings of that length (as in the NP argument above). We can do this in polynomial space. If we find that $B$ is reached, then we accept. If the counter runs out and we did not reach $B$, then since we iterated long enough, we know $B$ is not reachable and so we may confidently reject.

So we have PSPACE completeness. QED

Comment: It might be good to mention that the assumption in the first sentence that $b$ has the same length as $a$ is no loss of generality, since it can be achieved by padding.

Comment: It might be worth to mention that the problem is PSPACE-complete, not just hard.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. I was confused about this for a bit, but now I see how to do it. I'll edit.

Comment: You don’t need to explicitly look for cycles. Either let the algorithm cycle forever (this is good enough under some definitions of space), or keep a counter and reject after $2^n$ steps (assuming binary alphabet).

Comment: Ah, yes, that is even simpler. And I was already counting to reject the candidate cycle!

Comment: This is essentially the content of one of the results of http://heim.ifi.uio.no/msteffen/download/02/iterating-jlap.pdf except of course one has to interpret what the OP means by program.

Comment: I clarified the situation that one has a different decision problem for each $P$. For any given $P$, we have the reachability problem that accepts or rejects strings $(A,B)$ of the same length, depending on whether $B=P^k(A)$ for some $k$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks. But do we have any schemes which solve the problem efficiently; granting that the result may be approximate (ref my second question).

Comment: Since the problem is PSPACE complete, we should not be expecting any efficient algorithms. The fastest algorithm I can see is the brute-force algorithm to compute all the iterations of $P$, and this takes exponential time.

Comment: Absolutly, but is there any [Polynomial-time approximation scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) for the problem at hand or the reachability problem. Because unless we have one; a problem having string length of say 20 characters from English  alphabet may well be impossible to solve through brute forcing.

Comment: Having even an approximation algorithm would seem difficult for this problem. You might try cstheory.stackexchange.com--perhaps they have some ideas.

Comment: Are you assuming that the program is at lease PSpace computable? Otherwise I don't see how you get that the problem is in PSpace.

Comment: @Kaveh, In the comments, the OP says that P is polytime computable.